# Design Pattern Need to remove a series of If.. elses in object initialization

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract-factory

I'm writing an application in which there will be multiple departments and for each department there will be separate processing class.
Each department and department processing is represented by separate class.

so, now main method in java looks more like series of if else ladder.

Is there any way of making it more flexible so that i can add more departments and their processing classes later without modifying the originally written class much ??

I've read about Abstract Factory patterns but is there any other solution than it ??

Comment: I don't understand how people are answering this question.  Your question isn't very clear, consider rewording.  It might help to post a "dumb"ed down example of what you currently have.

Comment: Do you see a problem with using an abstract factory pattern?

Comment: well, there is no problem but i just want to consider all possible options before going for the actual implementation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Abstract Factory pattern is probably best suited to the scenario that you described. You will need a heirarchy of Department Processors and a matching heirarchy of Department classes. The Abstract factory will produce a concrete factory for each pair based on some discriminator, process the department for you and return the Department object.

The rest of your application does not need to be aware of the differences in the creation of the department objects since it will use the FActory to get a department simply passing the appropriate discriminator.

Adding a new department will require the new department clas, the processor class and updating the factory logic.

---

Alternatively, if the structure of the departments are all the same but the processing is different you may consider using something like the Strategy pattern. In this case you have a single Department, but the deccision about processing will be made for the Strategy instead. So the appropriate Strategy is injected into the department and the department's behaviour differs accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Create an interface to hide the departments, like "Department". Write your main method like:

```
main() {
    String criteria = ...; // this is how we choose the department to use,
                           // and you probably don't want to use a String
                           // but some other, more expressive type
    for (Department department : departments) {
        if (department.supports(criteria)) {
            department.doWhatever();
        }
    }
}
```

Then use dependency injection to populate the `departments` collection. Depending on how you set it up, it could be pure configuration.

Comment: Using a String to encapsulate something that is probably complex and should be in its own class...  doesn't seem a very good practice.

Comment: @Atreys: I agree. The main method also should take a String[] argument. It's just an example. Added to the code example to make it explicit.

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole web site devoted to the topic.  You want to use polymorphism and possibly reflection depending on what you are trying to do.

http://www.antiifcampaign.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can create enum with field for each state. Then create abstract method `init()` in the enum and implement it for each member.

In your code you can get state from for example properties file and then say `State.valueOf(state).init()`

Comment: are we allowed to have abstract methods in enum as well ??

Comment: An enum can have abstract methods and implement an interface, however each enum value must implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the "Factory" or the "Abstract Factory" design pattern would be the first step. That would take the object initialization logic out of your main code and isolate it in the factory classes. In that way, your main code would be closed for modification and open for extension (a.k.a. [Open Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29)). The changes you make will be isolated in the factory classes.

If you want to take this one step further, you may also use reflection. An example would be:

```
static Object createObject(String className) {
  Object object = null;
  try {
      Class classDefinition = Class.forName(className);
      object = classDefinition.newInstance();
  } catch (InstantiationException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
  }
  return object;
}
```

With this code, you can simply create an object like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewDepartment dep = (NewDepartment) createObject("yourpackage.NewDepartment");
}
```

Of course, there is a [trade-off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459345/disadvantages-advantages-of-reflection) when you use reflection. That is up your discretion to use it or not.